# How to set up virtual windows so it shares graphic card via IOMMU?

Tags: vmware, xen, linux-kvm, qemu, hypervisor

I'd like to continue using Linux as my desktop system. But from time to time I'd like to do some gaming. I know that I can use Wine and PlayOnLinux stuff, but it doesn't always work. I also know, that I can just dual boot Linux & Windows, but it prevents me of using both systems simultaneously (e.g. performing calculations in Linux while playing games on Windows :-) ).

I know that in theory the IOMMU technology can allow lending the graphic card to Windows. There is even a list of [IOMMU-compatible hardware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOMMU_hardware_list). And suppose I have met the hardware requirements.

1. What options do I have to combine Windows and Linux guests under some hypervisor in such a way, that I can easily switch between them, and at least Windows has a direct access to graphic card through IOMMU (so I can use native drivers)?
2. Is it doable at present?
3. How exactly the process of changing which guest OS owns display occur? Is it instantaneous? Is the video memory shared?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be what you are looking [for](http://www.overclock.net/t/1205216/guide-create-a-gaming-virtual-machine#). Sounds like it is possible, but bleeding edge.

Comment: You should add more detail to this answer, or it will likely be converted into a comment. For example, include some details from the link you provided.